# Android device: glass broken and not able to enter lock screen password

Tags: android

I have an Android device with a broken screen and no root access. The device is locked with a password which I cannot enter as the touch screen does not work anymore.
Connecting a Bluetooth keyboard is not an option as the device does not have Bluetooth enabled.
Also, connecting an USB keyboard is not possible as the device does not support it.

Does anyone know a way to "inject" the password so that I can unlock the device and pull my personal data off so that I can have it repaired (and factory reset)?
I have the current password, it's just not possible to enter it anymore...

Is there a way to programmatically remote-control settings.apk and remove the password protection using some APK?
(I could install it using adb sideload, listening for the BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast and automatically change the setting)

I know that this is a difficult story as it might be some kind of security breach, but I would also accept other solutions. It's just that I cannot think of any. Maybe Google already has taken this scenario into account and provides some more elegant way to accomplish this.

Does anyone have an idea how to get this job done?

Comment: No problem - send/take the device to a repair shop that services the device.  Have the sceen replaced.  Job done.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Android usage, belongs to http://android.stackexchange.com (Mobile device usage is not in scope of Super User!)

Comment: I know this is closed and fairly old, but I needed a solution and maybe this will ehlp someone else who fnids this post. I just came across this web page: http://joyofandroid.com/unlock-android-device-with-cracked-or-broken-screen/

I haven't tried either method. The first requires debug mode to be on. mine isn't. the second option is something I hadn't thought about - a USB mouse with an on-the-go adaptor

Comment: If you have USB-Debugging/ADB enabled on your phone and your PC is authorized for debugging on your phone then you can try one of the follwing tools:
1. Vysor http://www.vysor.io/
2. MonkeyRemote https://github.com/ns130291/MonkeyRemote/releases

Answer (score 1):

If you have USB Debugging enabled, you can try a few different tricks. First off, are you using a pattern or code? Looks like there's an easy way to reset the pattern and make it take any new pattern, but no way via ADB to then unlock it with pattern. And if your digitizer is messed up, I guess that doesn't help a whole lot.

However, if you're not using pattern lock, looks like you can send key events to your phone via adb shell using the "input" command, e.g: $ input keyevent 26 # should turn on/off the screen

It's also possible to write a program to that listens to BOOT_COMPLETED and disables the keyguard I think.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem that anyone has developed any universal methods for this, much less ones that are up to date. Looks like someone had what you wanted in a CM7 ROM but they had "Menu Unlock" option enabled, so sending the Menu key event via ADB accomplished it.

Sources:

http://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-bypass-disable-pattern-unlock-on-android-via-adb-commands/ (see for how to reset your pattern)

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1134978 (for hints at how to disable keyguard entirely using a program you'd sideload)

Comment: I must note a lot of these system settings are configurable in ways like in the first source. You might be able to flip some other settings using the sqlite interface. There ought to be a configuration option somewhere for disabling the lockscreen entirely.

Comment: Here's another useful link -- this one has example for flipping the screen timeout so it doesn't timeout as well as disabling the keyguard entirely. Note it's for Android 4.1 so it may not work on 4.4 necessarily.

http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51562/unlock-screen-with-adb-android-4-1-2

Answer (score 0):

have you tried [Android Screencast](https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)?
you can control your Android remotely from desktop